# Why does my remote modal not show .modal-header or footer?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Here is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript that relates to the modal:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    $(this).removeData('modal');
});

$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function (e) {
    lv_target = $(this).attr('data-target')
    lv_url = $(this).attr('href')
    $(lv_target).load(lv_url)});
```

Here is my link code: `<a href="http://localhost:3000/hints/found_sentences?word=创造" class="old_hint" data-remote="true" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">造</a>`

When I click on the link it shows up with *all* of the divs replaced instead of just the `"modal-body"` div. In other words, `Modal header` doesn't appear above the remote content.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webmagnets/W3TLJ/). Disregard the content that loads. Just notice that the modal-header and modal-footer content doesn't show.

Comment: Your problem is, `Modal header` doesn't appear? or what? I'm a bit confused. What do you want the display would be?

Comment: Yes. The modal header and footer doesn't appear.

Comment: It worked fine, I tested it. The moddal has the `header`, `body`, and the `footer`. Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to simulate your problem?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle you asked for: `http://jsfiddle.net/webmagnets/W3TLJ/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/kulldox/W3TLJ/3/

The problem was here:

```
<a href="/favicon.png" class="old_hint" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">你</a>
```

You should've remove the 'data-remote="true"' in the trigger element. First of all it's not a Boolean attribute. And second, documentation states that you should use either href or data-remote attributes, not both.

Also you were missing the closing "}" from the click.

Comment: Why don't your lines end in `;`? Also, what is the last `}` for? When I add that it closes my `$(document).ready(function () {` and then the rest of the code from my js file doesn't run.

Comment: The "}" is closing the anonymous function from the click method. The missing ";" are also from your initial fiddle code. Here's the fiddle with the necessary ";" http://jsfiddle.net/kulldox/W3TLJ/5/

Comment: Those last 3 characters still break the rest of my code. Here is a fiddle with the full code - `http://jsfiddle.net/webmagnets/RJDSx/`

Comment: Are you not able to tell me what you did to fix it?

Comment: Changed: `$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function (e) {
        target = $(this).attr('data-target');
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $(target).find('.modal-body').load(url);
    });`. Your code was: `$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function (e) {
    lv_target = $(this).attr('data-target')
    lv_url = $(this).attr('href')
    $(lv_target).load(lv_url)});`

Answer (score 0):

You replace the content of whole modal, not modal's body.

```
$(lv_target).find('.modal-body').load(lv_url);
```

Comment: Could you please update my jsfiddle and put the new link here so I can see that it works?